# Filtering database by multiple fields when some fields may not be filled out

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to build a filter functionality where the user can fill out as many inputs on the form page as they like. So they may leave some filters blank. How do I search my database for only the values the user has submitted? The only way I know how to do this would be a massive cluster of if statements to account for every possible combination of forms they filled out, e.g.:

```
<?php

if(isset($max) && isset($min) && isset($rank)) {

    mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM books WHERE ...")

} else if (isset($max) && (isset($min))) {

    // so on and so forth

}
```

Now the code above may look manageable, and it would be if I only had 3 filters, but in this case I have a fairly large list of filters that I only need to apply if the user submitted something. All-in-all I think there is something like 30 potential combinations of the different filters.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: where do you get the fields from ? please provide the full example

Comment: Sorry, the fields are being posted from the previous page. I just wrote variables as an example, but it would be along the lines of `if(isset($_POST['max']))`. I should add I think I just had an idea - perhaps check if each field isset and build a string that concatenates each search filter if the field is set and then run that string as the SQL search.

Comment: check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the query string part by part. First you set:

```
$s = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE 1 ";
```

Then on each and every filter you write:

```
if(isset(...)) {
    $s .= " AND myfield = $myvalue ";
}
```

And in the end you can append:

```
$s .= " ORDER BY somewhat;";
```

Of course some escaping should be done or better use mysqli_ queries.

Placing the condition '1' right after `WHERE` helps you use the `AND` operator in each line regadles of is it the first active condition or not. You can put the condiotions in a `while` loop if your `POST` data is well structured. You can name your HTML input fileds as 'filter[1]', 'filter[2]' and so on and then you can iterate on them with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Action points

- define an array *(v)* of all the possible values keys
- [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) *(v)* and [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) *$_POST* with the *new (v)*
- [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the *new (v)* to remove unfilled/blank values (or filter by your custom callback if you also want to include null/false values)
- [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the *new (v)* by key and value using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to build the query

So

```
$possibleValuesKeys = ['min', 'max', 'rank', ...];
$values = array_filter(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($possibleValuesKeys)));
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', array_map(
   function ($v, $k) { return sprintf("%s = '%s' ", $k, $v); },
   $values,
   array_keys($values)
))
```

Comment: Good approach. I would suggest to implode with ` AND ` rather than a comma.

Comment: thnx 4 the feedback